# Grails use findAll in a domain class

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Can I call `findAll` on a domain class from within that domain class?

```
class MyClass {

    Parents parent
    ///...

    def onLoad(){     
        MyClass.findAll('from MyClass where parent:=parent',[parent:parent]);
    }
}
```

When I try, I get a no signature method findAll available for MyClass error.

Comment: so far the answer is yes but with some very spooky ghosts in the machine...like every other row being filled with null values..???

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your issue is calling `findAll` from within a domain class.

You seem to have some syntax issues going on...

What you probably want is:

```
MyClass.findAll('from MyClass m where m.parent=:parent', [parent:parent])
```

[*findAll* documentation](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/ref/Domain%20Classes/findAll.html)

or

```
MyClass.findAllByParent(parent)
```

[*findAllBy* documentation](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/ref/Domain%20Classes/findAllBy.html)

Comment: yeah, typo in my question. findAll error seemingly related to cache. After clearing and recompiling, it's running but with UNEXPECTED behavior. Some rows return full of null values for seemingly no reason.

Comment: If you want to do HQL queries, it's best to use the `executeQuery` method.